# Update value from previous row value using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This question is a variation of my older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785805/update-null-column-value-from-non-null-value-in-previous-row). I hope to explain the problem using an example. So

**Sample Data**
Here is sample data to work with:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (GID      int,             Seq     int, 
                     IsLive   bit,             Eff     date, 
                     Name     varchar(50),     Salary  decimal) 

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 4, 0, '01-11-2012',  NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'GSM', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

**Following, are two *sample result sets*.  Although the snippet shows *inserts* the point is to show what acceptable *output set* would look like:**

**Sample Output #1**
In the data set below when a row has `IsLive=0` then the value from its columns must over write the value of the same columns on the rows where `IsLive=1` below it skipping NULL values. Ignore any `IsLive=1` rows before the first `IsLive=0` row.

```
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 4, 0, '01-11-2012',  NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'GSM', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'GSM', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSI', NULL)

    SELECT * FROM @Test AS FakedOutput_1
```

**Sample Output #2**
In the data set below when a row has `IsLive=0` then the value from its columns must over write the value of the same columns on the rows where `IsLive=1` below it. Columns with NULL values take the value from the previous row.

```
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    -- <- the following row is different from prev
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'RTA', NULL) 
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'RTA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'GSM', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'GSM', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', 'FSA', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', NULL)
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSI', NULL)

    SELECT * FROM @Test AS FakedOutput_2
```

**Attempted Solution**
Here is what I have come up with so far, but it fails my first test case (`GID=1`)

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    SELECT  T.GID, T.SEQ, T.IsLive, NULL cGuid, NULL cSEQ, 
            cast(0 as bit) cIsLive, T.Name, T.Salary 
    FROM    @Test T
    JOIN    @Test S ON T.GID = S.GID AND T.Seq = S.Seq AND S.IsLive = 0
    -- - - - - - - 
      UNION ALL 
    -- - - - - - - 
    SELECT  t.GID, t.SEQ, T.IsLive, c.GID cGID, c.Seq cSEQ, 
             c.IsLive cIsLive, ISNULL(C.Name, T.Name), 
             ISNULL(t.Salary, c.Salary) 
    FROM    CTE c 
    JOIN    @Test t ON    t.GID     = c.GID   AND 
                          t.Seq     > c.Seq   AND 
                          t.IsLive  = 1       AND 
                          c.IsLive  = 0
    -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
) 
--SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY CTE.GID, CTE.Seq
UPDATE  t 
SET     Name = c.Name, Salary = c.Salary
FROM    @Test t 
JOIN    CTE c     ON c.GID = t.GID AND c.Seq = t.SEQ
WHERE   C.cIsLive IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Mahmoud: Thanks, was just in the process of fixing the formatting.

Comment: @GilM you might want to take a stab at this since you nailed the previous one!

Comment: I made a bit of a mess with updating the post, I cant seem to format (or rather I dont know how to format) the newly added test cases :(

Answer (score 1):

Using `APPLY` works for your test case. The following gives the same as your solution 2

```
SELECT  t1.GID,
        t1.Seq,
        t1.IsLive,
        t1.Eff,
        CASE WHEN t1.IsLive = 0 THEN COALESCE(t1.Name, t3.Name) ELSE COALESCE(t3.Name, t1.Name) END AS Name,
        Salary
FROM    @Test T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Name
            FROM    @Test T2
            WHERE   T2.GID = T1.GID
            AND     T2.Seq < T1.Seq
            AND     t2.IsLive = 0
            AND     t2.Name IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Seq DESC
        ) t3
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that an `UPDATE` was required:

```
UPDATE  @Test
SET     Name = CASE WHEN t1.IsLive = 0 THEN COALESCE(t1.Name, t3.Name) ELSE COALESCE(t3.Name, t1.Name) END
FROM    @Test T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Name
            FROM    @Test T2
            WHERE   T2.GID = T1.GID
            AND     T2.Seq < T1.Seq
            AND     t2.IsLive = 0
            AND     t2.Name IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Seq DESC
        ) t3
```

**EDIT 2**

I have altered the query inside the apply slightly, now it will try and find the closest row where live = 0 and the name is not null, if there are no rows where live = 1 (as in GID = 4) it will take the closest row where the name is not null:

```
UPDATE  @Test
SET     Name = CASE WHEN t1.IsLive = 0 THEN COALESCE(t1.Name, t3.Name) ELSE COALESCE(t3.Name, t1.Name) END
FROM    @Test T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Name
            FROM    @Test T2
            WHERE   T2.GID = T1.GID
            AND     T2.Seq < T1.Seq
            AND     t2.Name IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY t2.IsLive, Seq DESC
        ) t3
```

Comment: thanks! I added a few more test cases. It works for all but one (Gid=3)

Comment: also this solution needs to work for n coulumns (hence the Salary column in the end but I haven't populated it). I am not sure this solution will do that.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to realize that this question is only a minor variation of my previous question posted. Just some time away from the keyboard helped me see the answer! @GarethDs answer contributed toward this as well.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  T.GID, T.SEQ, T.IsLive, Name, Salary 
    FROM    @Test T
    JOIN    ( SELECT   GID, MIN(Seq) Seq 
              FROM     @Test 
              GROUP BY GID     
            ) S ON T.GID = S.GID AND T.Seq = S.Seq

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT t.GID, t.SEQ, T.IsLive,
           CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 0 THEN COALESCE(T.Name, C.Name) 
                ELSE COALESCE(C.Name, T.Name) END,
           CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 0 THEN COALESCE(T.Salary, C.Salary) 
                ELSE COALESCE(C.Salary, T.Salary) END 
    FROM   CTE C
    JOIN   @Test T ON T.GID = C.GID AND T.SEQ = C.SEQ+1 
) 
--SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY CTE.GID, CTE.Seq
UPDATE T 
SET    Name   = C.Name,  
       Salary =  C.Salary
FROM   @Test T
JOIN   CTE C ON C.GID = T.GID AND C.Seq = T.SEQ
```